# Join two table in zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework

I need to join two tables in zend_validate_Db_NoRecordExists. I need to use exclude for each table. I am using `postgresql` as db. 
The usual way of invoking `zend_validate_Db_NoRecordExists` is as follows:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
                   array (
                    'table' => 'table1',
                    'field' => 'flag',
                    'exclude' => 'delete=0',
                    )
                    );
```

Comment: Didn't Zend 2 get released?

Comment: @Denis, What does Zend 2's release have to do with this?

Comment: @saji89: Just pointing it out as a comment, since OP will end up needing to maintain his code in the aftermath... http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#supported-options-for-zend-validator-db

Comment: @Denis, That's surely something to think of. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you must me able to use

`$validator->getSelect()->_joinUsing($type, $name, $cond);`

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a use case.

Comment: It fails when two ids having different field name